# .htaccess not working in digital ocean server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

When I use the .htaccess as followed, I am getting `The requested URL was not found on this server`
 error. My configurations are as

Digitalocean: var/www/html/my_site/*.htaccess* as

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  # Rules to serve URLs which point to files directly
  # ----------
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I changed /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
from

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

To

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The file `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf` as

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
   DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```

I changed myapp\application\config\config.php as `$config['index_page'] = '';` and `$config['uri_protocol']    = 'REQUEST_URI';`

And I have run the following commands in my digitalocean server

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 reload
```

When I opening my_site in browser, after done all this I am getting the following message
[image: Not Found]

If I remove the .htaccess and reset myapp\application\config\config.php as `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` It is working. So pls help.

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this

```
<Directory /var/www/html/my_site/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```